# Spring MVC : Request Mapping not found while extending a BaseController in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I am extending my `BaseController` with `SubBaseController` to include some more request mappings.

To avoid duplicate mappings I have excluded the `BaseController` from `controllers.xml` using `exclude-filter`.

```
<context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.cart.controller.BaseController" />
@Controller
@RequestMapping("cart")

public class BaseController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> addToCart(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("cart")

public class SubBaseController extends BaseController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> removeCart(HttpServletRequest request) {

    }
}
```

Note: Getting 403 while accessing `/cart/add`. I can no longer access the mappings defined in `BaseController`. However I can access `/cart/remove`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two different classes put both the methods in same class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("cart")

public class BaseController {
   @ResponseBody
   @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public Map<String, Object> addToCart(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

   }

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> removeCart(HttpServletRequest request) {

}
}
```

Read through [spring controller documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-controller) for better understanding of controllers